# MySQL trigger doesn't work?

Tags: mysql, triggers

so i've got this test coming up and i'm doing the practice-test, but somehow my trigger won't work. I've done exactly as i have been taught, but it just won't work. Can anybody help me?

i created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE DiscountActions(
discountID int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
dishName varchar(70) NOT NULL,
type varchar(70) NOT NULL,
discountPercentage varchar(70) NOT NULL,
startdate date NOT NULL,
enddate date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (discountID)
);
```

and i want to add this trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `checkStartDatum` 
AFTER INSERT ON `DiscountActions`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF NEW.startdate < DATE(NOW()) 
     THEN DELETE 
        FROM DiscountActions
        WHERE startdate = NEW.startdate;
  END IF ;
END ; 
//
```

but when i add it, the following error appears: i get the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN DELETE FROM kortingactie WHERE begindatum = NEW.b' at line 6

What it's supposed to do is this: When you add a new DiscountAction, it should check whether or not the startdate is in the past. If the startdate is in the past, it should delete the entire discount action, as it isn't possible.

Comment: What error are you receiving when you run this query?

Comment: i get the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN DELETE FROM kortingactie WHERE begindatum = NEW.b' at line 6

Comment: yes it is @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Tried it, works perfectly for me. Did you copy&paste it from somewhere? Maybe there are hidden control symbols in there?

Comment: wow... i tried it over a dozen times, no results at all... i did wrote it from an example. So no, i haven't copied it. i'll try it once again...

Comment: nope, still not working... i get this error now: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 11. but if i remove the delimiter at the end, it suddenly works? wow....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing syntacticly wrong with your trigger. Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38242)** that shows that. But unfortunately your trigger won't work. You'll end up with an error when the condition will be met

> Can't update table 'discountactions' in stored function/trigger
>   because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>   function/trigger.

Now to prevent an insertion of a row if `startdate` < current date you can:

1. change a trigger from `AFTER` to `BEFORE` trigger
2. if condition is met simply violate one of the existing constraints. Since `startdate` in your table has a `NOT NULL` constraint we can utilize that.

Here is what a working version of your trigger might look like

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkStartDatum
BEFORE INSERT ON DiscountActions
FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.startdate = IF(NEW.startdate < CURDATE(), NULL, NEW.startdate);
```

It's a one-statement trigger so you don't even need to change a delimiter.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4058/1)** demo. Uncomment the last insert statement and see that the trigger won't allow the insertion.